# MongoClient PHP sript run for forever

Tags: php, mongodb

I am connecting with the mongodb remote host with PHP mongoclient class.

I have wrote nothing special simple but simple connection code.

```
$connection_url = "mongodb://{$dbuser}:{$dbpass}@{$dburl}:{$dbport}/{$dbname}";         
$this->m = new MongoClient($connection);
```

It does connect to mongodb but after some time my application hangs, By hangs I mean php sript run forever, no response and at last apache and my server crashes. I needs to restart my server to get it up again.

Why the PHP script is running forever and the mongoserver is not responding.

I have `max_execution_time` set to 30 seconds.

MongoClient version 1.4.5

Update:

As explained [here](http://blog.mongolab.com/2013/10/do-you-want-a-timeout/)
The default connection and socket time out of mongodb is **never timeout** , I guess, may be the php MongoClient is waiting for forever if socket is closed from MongoServer side.

To make sure I have set options for mongoclient to not to wait more than 5 seconds if the socket is closed, like below

```
$connection_url = "mongodb://{$dbuser}:{$dbpass}@{$dburl}:{$dbport}/{$dbname}";
$options = array('connectTimeoutMS' =>5000 , 'socketTimeoutMS' => 5000);
$this->m = new MongoClient($connection, $options);
```

But this still hangs

Here is the short Mongo Log

> 2:4:found connection
>   somehost;-;dbname/user/fd6da21ee7cf37731eb88e250d4a05d6;1957 (looking
>   for somehost;-;dbname/username/fd6da21ee7cf37731eb88e250d4a05d6;1957)
>   2:2:mongo_get_read_write_connection: finding a STANDALONE connection
>
> 2:4:found connection
>   host;-;dbname/username/fd6da21ee7cf37731eb88e250d4a05d6;1957 (looking
>   for hostname;-;dnname/user/fd6da21ee7cf37731eb88e250d4a05d6;1957)
>
> 2:2:is_ping: pinging
>   hostname;-;dbname/username/fd6da21ee7cf37731eb88e250d4a05d6;1957

There is no log after 'is_ping'. This means that my script hangs here.

Update:

Here is what processes are using and running when it hangs

```
ps aux | sort -rk 3,3 | head -n 20
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
www-data 32612  0.0  1.1 108372  5604 ?        S    11:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 32390  0.0  1.1 108372  5604 ?        S    11:04   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 32389  0.0  1.4 109192  7348 ?        S    11:00   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 32388  0.0  1.4 109192  7376 ?        S    11:00   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 32387  0.0  1.4 109192  7376 ?        S    11:00   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 32386  0.0  1.2 108412  6100 ?        S    11:00   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 32385  0.0  1.8 111692  9432 ?        S    11:00   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 31833  0.0  1.5 109216  7548 ?        S    02:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 31173  0.0  1.5 108824  7872 ?        S    Mar02   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15538  0.0  1.5 109216  7664 ?        S    Mar02   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15536  0.0  1.4 109200  7496 ?        S    Mar02   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15535  0.0  1.6 110904  8444 ?        S    Mar02   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15534  0.0  1.3 108684  6536 ?        S    Mar02   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
whoopsie   847  0.0  0.5 187668  2676 ?        Ssl  Feb24   0:00 whoopsie
syslog     370  0.0  0.6 249676  3060 ?        Sl   Feb24   0:31 rsyslogd -c5
root       984  0.0  0.1  15792   908 tty1     Ss+  Feb24   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
root       946  0.0  2.0 108348 10120 ?        Ss   Feb24   0:32 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb24   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root       879  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb24   0:00 [kvm-irqfd-clean]
```

Comment: I'm getting this error too, I'm using SSL, but I do not think the issue is SSL - its just the sockets becoming stale.  If I find an answer, I'll surely post it here for you.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like an hardware problem or mongodb problem, server should not need any restart if there are hanging php scripts...

but, you can try to add username password db to the options like this:

```
function __construct($host, $username, $password, $db){
    $this->client = new MongoClient("mongodb://" . $host, array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'db' => $db));
    $this->db = $this->client->selectDB($db);
}
```

Comment: tried. this does not make any change. still same issue.